# Python ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.I'm getting this value error and I don't know how to solve the issue

Tags: python, valueerror

```
def simulate(self, timesteps, **kwargs):
    pos = {comp: i for i, comp in enumerate(kwargs)}
    population = np.zeros(len(pos), dtype='int')

    for comp in pos:
        population[pos[comp]] = kwargs[comp]  # line where the error is 

    values = []
    values.append(population)

    comps = list(self.transitions.nodes)
    time = np.arange(1, timesteps, 1, dtype='int')

    for t in time:
        pop = values[-1]
        new_pop = values[-1].copy()
        N = np.sum(pop)
```

I am having this value error and I'm not sure on how to fix it. Any suggestion

Error happens when I call this,

if population is None:
        population = SIR1.values_.iloc[-1].copy()
    else:
        population = pd.concat([population, SIR1.values_.iloc[-1]])

```
S0 = population.S
I00 = population.I
R0 = population.R

Quarantine.simulate(365 - 74, S=S0, I=I00, R=R0) ### Line causing the error
```

Comment: Please post the exact error and the line where it occurs

Comment: Exact Error is line: population[pos[comp]] = kwargs[comp]

Comment: We'd also need to know how you called this function - with what parameters.

Comment: Are `pos[comp]` are integers? Because if they aren't you can't index with them

Comment: Dont ever post text as screenshots

Comment: post error + traceback